# I want to make a bot that finds a person on discord with only their username by typing their username and followed by 0001 to 9999

Tags: python, types, automation, discord, pynput

This is what I have so far:

```
for i in range(1000):
    current = print("USERNAMEHERE#"+str(i).zfill(4))
    time.sleep(.5)
    keyboard.press(current)
    keyboard.release(current)
```

I want to make it type out the current str value of current

Answer (score 0):

You can use `keyboard.type()` to let the keyboard type out a given string. You can find it in the [documentation](https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html?highlight=keyboard#controlling-the-keyboard).

So to get it to type out the value of current, you'd do `keyboard.type(current)`